# If statements with Go

Tags: go

I am playing around with Go. I want to make it so when someone enters 'hi' it prints hiii

Here is my code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func main(){

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println("Simple Shell")
    fmt.Println("---------------------")

    for {
        fmt.Print("-> ")
        text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if (text == "hi") {
            fmt.Println("hiii")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question

Comment: from the [`ReadString`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) docs:  `ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to and including the delimiter.`

Answer (score 3):

There is a trick to that: When using ReadString and ReadBytes function with a delimiter, the returned string (and bytes) contains the delimiter. That's why the condition is not true, your actual string is "hi\n" and not "hi".

In order to read from stdin, you can use the ReadLine function, or manually trim the end line characters with packages `strings` and `bytes`.

Also, you can use a Scanner, it reads lines by default. Here are some examples which all do the same job:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("-> ")
    text, _, _ := reader.ReadLine()
    if string(text) == "hi" {
        fmt.Println("hii")
    }

    fmt.Print("-> ")
    stext, _ := reader.ReadString('\n') // stext ends with '\n', it reads the delimiter
    stext = strings.TrimRight(stext, "\n")
    if stext == "hi" {
        fmt.Println("hii")
    }

    fmt.Print("-> ")
    text, _ = reader.ReadBytes('\n')
    text = bytes.TrimRight(text, "\n")
    if string(text) == "hi" {
        fmt.Println("hii")
    }

    fmt.Print("-> ")
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Scan()
    stext = scanner.Text()
    if stext == "hi" {
        fmt.Println("hii")
    }

    fmt.Print("−> ")
    scanner.Scan()
    text = scanner.Bytes()
    if string(text) == "hi" {
        fmt.Println("hii")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `\n` such that

```
if text == "hi\n" {
    fmt.Println("hiii")
}
```